# Netlogo : issue with observer context

Tags: netlogo, procedure

When running two exact same procedures for specific patches, one of the two is stating an error because **"it cannot be run in observer context, it is a patches/turtles context only".**

```
to start
ask patches with [seed = 1 AND age = retirement-age] [retirement]
ask patches with [seed = 1 AND age = death] [successor]
end
```

The `retirement-age` is an input from the interface.

The `death` is a patch property, I tried the `start`procedure as well with an input from the interface.

The retirement and death procedure are just a copy-paste of each other, using lists created in other procedures. Only the result is different, see below :

```
to retirement
;;; other calculations same as successor procedure
 ifelse (successor-result = 1) [set age 35 ] [set over-retirement 1]
end

    to successor
   ;;; other calculations same as retirement procedure
     ifelse (successor-result = 1) [set age 18] [dispatch-parcels] 
    end
```

Running the retirement procedure do not create error, **but the successor procedure does create an error.**

I did not copy-paste everything because I don't think it is useful as the two procedure are exactly the same. The other calculations use global variables and lists created in other procedures in the observer context.

Here-below is the `dispatch-parcels` procedure that regards to concerned patches from the beginning.

```
to dispatch-parcels
 ;; this regards the patches with seed = 1 that has been processed in the successor procedure. But doesn't work as for updating the age and death of the agent
  set seed 0
  set age 0
  set death 0

  ;; if there is no successor, the parcels of the farm are distributed along the closest parcels : one farm can distribute its own parcels to multiple different farms
  ask patches with [ ID-farm = [ID-farm] of myself]

  ;; for each parcel, finds the closest parcel and use the ID-farm as the new ID-farm, same for the region in case it changes.
  [
    set ID-farm ([ID-farm] of (min-one-of patches with [(ID-farm != 0) AND (ID-farm != [ID-farm] of myself)]  [distance myself] ))
    set region ([region] of (min-one-of patches with [(region != 0) AND (region != [region] of myself)]  [distance myself] ))
  ]

end
```

I also tried to the `successor` procedure with the same final command line  as from the `retirement` procedure but I get the same error message. So there should be something "hidden" somewhere about this  `successor` procedure.

Any insight about the likely source of error, what I should more attention to ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi Sarah, could you give us the dispatch-parcels procedure? That's the only place I could see that could make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. It was so obvious that it became invisible and I'm a bit embarrased.
I'd like to share my answer anyway because it might opened the eyes of tired beginners like me.

In order to test this part of my code, I created a button to only test the successor procedure, which was in `observer` context, which was not possible with the commands I wrote. That's just it.